# Domain is still domain after excluding one singular point

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $G\subset\mathbb C$ be a domain. Show that $G\backslash \{z_0\}$ is a domain for any $z_0\in G$.

It is easy to show that $G\backslash \{z_0\}$ is still open in $\mathbb C$. But I'm not sure how to prove that it's also a path connected space again. My idea would be that for any $\epsilon>0:\ K_\epsilon(z_0)\cap G\neq \emptyset $ ($K_\epsilon (r)$ being the open disk) so for every path $\gamma$ through $z_0$ I can choose a partial path around $z_0$ in the disk $K_\epsilon(z_0)$ that still is in $G$. Is this idea correct? And if so, how do I put it mathematically correct?

Comment: Your idea is correct. If you want a path connecting say $a$ with $b$, and there was a path $\gamma$ connecting $a$ with $b$ passing through $z_0$, it would suffice to take a circle with center $z_0$ and radius $\epsilon<\min\{|z_0-a|,|z_0-b|\}$, and change any the part of the path $\gamma$ inside the disc $B(z_0,\epsilon)$ by an arc on the circle.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!